# Countably Infinitely Many Points in a Euclidean Space with Restraining Orders

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, hilbert-spaces, euclidean-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

***Update.***  The answer to the main question for $d\geq 3$ is positive.  For $d=1$, it is easy to show that the answer is negative.  What is the answer for $d=2$?

> **Main Question.** Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of positive integers.  Do there exist $d\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there are pairwise distinct
> points $x_1$, $y_1$, $x_2$, $y_2$, $\ldots$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such
> that
>
> (i) $\left\|x_i-y_i\right\|_2 >1$ for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$,
>
> (ii) $\left\|x_i-y_j\right\|_2<1$ for all $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
> $i\neq j$,
>
> (ii) $\left\|x_i-x_j\right\|_2<1$ and $\left\|y_i-y_j\right\|_2<1$ for all $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$?
>
> Here, $\|\bullet\|_2$ is the usual Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

***Alternative Interpretation.*** Let $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $\ldots$ and $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$, $\ldots$ be two countably infinite collections of people.  Suppose that $a_i$ and $b_i$ have a restraining order against one another for every $i=1,2,3,\ldots$.  No other pair of people has a restraining order.  However, each person is friends with every other persons except the one against whom they have a restraining order.  For a fixed dimension $d\in\mathbb{N}$, is it possible to arrange these people in the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space so that the distance between each pair of friends is less than $1$, but the distance between each pair with a restraining order is greater than $1$?

This question is based on [Graph theory-related problem, unit distance graph, pairs of people with restraining orders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363860/graph-theory-related-problem-unit-distance-graph-pairs-of-people-with-restrain/).  If we require finitely many points, the answer is positive.  If we require uncountably many points, the answer is negative.  Hence, I wonder what happens if there are countably infinitely many points.

> **Related Question:** Let $J$ be an index set.  For a given cardinality of $J$, do there exist pairwise distinct
> points $x_i$ and $y_i$ for $i\in J$ in the real Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$ such
> that
>
> (i) $\left\|x_i-y_i\right\|_2 >1$ for every $i\in J$,
>
> (ii) $\left\|x_i-y_j\right\|_2<1$ for all $i,j\in J$ such that
> $i\neq j$,
>
> (ii) $\left\|x_i-x_j\right\|_2<1$ and $\left\|y_i-y_j\right\|_2<1$ for all $i,j\in J$?
>
> Here, $\|\bullet\|_2$ is the usual $2$-norm on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$.

---

***Attempt at the Main Question.***

Suppose that $S:=\big\{x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,\ldots\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ satisfies the required properties above.  We observe that $S$ is a bounded set, whence, due to the Heine-Borel Theorem, its topological closure $\bar{S}$ is compact, making it also sequentially compact.  Therefore, the sequence $\left\{x_i\right\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a subsequence $\left\{x_{i_j}\right\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging to a point $u$ in $\bar{S}$.  Now, the sequence $\left\{y_{i_j}\right\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a subsequence $\left\{y_{i_{j_k}}\right\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging to a point $v\in\bar{S}$.  We denote $u_k$ for $x_{i_{j_k}}$ and $v_k$ for $y_{i_{j_k}}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.  Hence, $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\,u_k=u$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\,v_k=v$.

Note that $\left\|u_i-v_i\right\|_2 >1$ and $\left\|u_i-v_j\right\|_2<1$ for all $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $i \neq j$.  Thus, $$\left\|u-v_j\right\|_2=\displaystyle \lim_{k\to\infty}\,\left\|u_k-v_j\right\|_2\leq 1 \text{ and }\left\|u_i-v\right\|=\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\,\left\|u_i-v_k\right\|_2\leq 1$$ for all $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$. Ergo, $\|u-v\|_2=\displaystyle\lim_{j\to\infty}\,\left\|u-v_j\right\|_2\leq 1$.  However, $$\|u-v\|_2=\displaystyle\lim_{i\to\infty}\,\left\|u_i-v_i\right\|_2\geq 1\,.$$  That is, $\|u-v\|_2=1$.

Comment: This _feels_ impossible in $\mathbb{R}^d$; I'm still wrapping my brain around it, but I feel like you could make an argument based on constraints around the accumulation points of the $x_i$ and $y_i$. (Note that conditions (ii) and (iii) together imply that the union of the $x$'s and $y$'s is contained in a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, so both have at least one accumulation point. This argument won't fly in the Hilbert space, of course.)

Comment: Also, this may be obvious but the 'inverse' ($x_i$ closer to $y_i$ but further from every $y_{\neq i}$) is definitely possible; we can put $x_i$ at $\langle 2^{-i}, \epsilon_i\rangle$ and $y_i$ at $\langle 2^{-i}, 1-\epsilon_i\rangle$ for suitably chosen $\epsilon_i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Main Question.* An answer is affirmative already for $d=3$. Indeed, for each $n$ put
$$x_n=\left(\frac 12\cos\frac{\pi}{n+1}, \frac 12\sin\frac{\pi}{n+1}, 0\right)$$ and
$$y_n=\left(-\frac 12\cos\frac{\pi}{n+1}, -\frac 12\sin\frac{\pi}{n+1}, \sin\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)(n+2)+1}\right).$$
Thus  $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of points of a circle in a plane $Oxy$ with radius $\frac 12$ centered at the origin, and $y_n=-x_n+\left(0,0, \sin\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)(n+2)+1}\right)$ for each $n$. It follows $\|x_n-y_n\|_2> 1$.

If $i<j$ then
$$4\|x_i-x_j\|^2_2\le 4\|y_i-y_j\|^2_2=$$
$$\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{i+1}-\cos\frac{\pi}{j+1}\right)^2+
\left(\sin\frac{\pi}{i+1}-\sin\frac{\pi}{j+1}\right)^2+
4\left(\sin\frac{\pi}{2(i+1)(i+2)+1}- \sin\frac{\pi}{2(j+1)(j+2)+1}\right)^2<$$
$$2-2\cos\frac{\pi}{i+1}\cos\frac{\pi}{j+1}-2\sin\frac{\pi}{i+1}\sin\frac{\pi}{j+1}+4\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2(i+1)(i+2)+1}=$$
$$2-2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{i+1}-\frac{\pi}{j+1}\right)+ 4\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2(i+1)(i+2)+1} =$$
$$4 \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2(i+1)}-\frac{\pi}{2(j+1)}\right)+ 4\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2(i+1)(i+2)+1}<$$
$$4 \sin^2\frac{\pi}{2(i+1)}+ 4\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2(i+1)(i+2)+1}\le $$
$$4 \sin^2\frac{\pi}{4}+ 4\sin^2\frac{\pi}{13}<4 \sin^2\frac{\pi}{4}+ 4\sin^2\frac{\pi}{6}=3<4.$$

If $i\ne j$ then

$$4\|x_i-y_j\|^2_2=$$
$$\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{i+1}+\cos\frac{\pi}{j+1}\right)^2+
\left(\sin\frac{\pi}{i+1}+\sin\frac{\pi}{j+1}\right)^2+
4\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2(j+1)(j+2)+1}=$$
$$2+2\cos\frac{\pi}{i+1}\cos\frac{\pi}{j+1}+2\sin\frac{\pi}{i+1}\sin\frac{\pi}{j+1}+4\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2(j+1)(j+2)+1}=$$
$$2+2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{i+1}-\frac{\pi}{j+1}\right)+ 4\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2(j+1)(j+2)+1} =$$
$$4-4\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2(i+1)}-\frac{\pi}{2(j+1)}\right)+4\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2(j+1)(j+2)+1}.$$

So it suffices to show that
$$\left|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2(i+1)}-\frac{\pi}{2(j+1)}\right)\right|>\sin \frac{\pi}{2(j+1)(j+2)+1}.$$
Put $m=\min\{i,j\}$. Then
$$\left|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2(i+1)}-\frac{\pi}{2(j+1)}\right)\right|\ge\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2(m+1)}-\frac{\pi}{2(m+2)}\right)=$$
$$\sin \frac{\pi}{2(m+1)(m+2)}>\sin \frac{\pi}{2(j+1)(j+2)+1}.$$

*Related question.* I guess by $\ell^2(\Bbb N,\Bbb R)$ you mean the usual $\ell_2$. Then the negative answer for an uncountable $J$ follows from the following

**Proposition**. If a metric space $(X,\rho)$ has contains families $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_i\}$ for $i\in J$ satisfying the respective conditions then $|J|\le d(X)$, where $d$ is the density of the space $X$.

*Proof*. For each $i\in J$ pick $\varepsilon_i>0$ such that $\rho(x_i, y_i)>1+2\varepsilon_i$. Then an open ball $B\left(x_i, 2\varepsilon_i\right)$ of radius $2\varepsilon_i$ centered at $x_i$ contains no other $x_j$. It follows that a family $\left\{B\left(x_i, \varepsilon_i \right):i\in J\right\}$ is a family of mutually disjoint non-empty open subsets of $X$. $\square$

Comment: This looks correct (I ran out of votes for the day, so I will upvote the answer tomorrow).  I will analyze the answer again.  Thanks!

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks. A main idea was to pick a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of points of a circle in a plane $Oxy$ with radius $\frac 12$ centered at the origin, and put $y_n=-x_n+(0,0,r_n)$ for each $n$, where $r_n$ is sufficiently small to assure $\|x_i-y_j\|<1$ for distinct $i,j$. I found this idea about two hours ago, but after then I had to listen two conference talks and carefully justify the values, this is why I was so slow.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the $\ell^2$ version, here is an easy argument you can find these points for $J$ countable, even on a sphere.

Note that if $(e_n)_n$ is the standard basis, then $d(\pm re_n,\pm re_m)=r^2\sqrt 2$ for $n\neq m$, and $d(re_n,-re_n)=2r$. So if we take any $r\in (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})$, then the sequences $x_n=re_n$, $y_n=-re_n$ are as desired.

An analogous argument works in any $\ell^p$ with $p>1$, and in fact shows that for a given cardinal $\kappa$, you can find the sequences with $\lvert J\rvert=\kappa$ in any $\ell^p(\kappa)$ with $p>1$. Paired with Alex's remark that the cardinality of this $J$ is at most the density of the metric space, it follows that the bound is sharp.